# qt ARP ubuntu super rights

Tags: qt, arp, root

I'm making an app that sends ARP packages. From the console,the program demands that I run it with super user rights using `sudo -s`.

Now I need to do an interface for the app using QT and I don't know how to give my app super user rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [gksudo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) or [kdesu](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kdesu).
It allows graphical programs to be run as root.

Comment: Shanmu         Thank you but I don't know how tu use these.Could you give me a simple example ?

Comment: Just like you run 'sudo -s <your program executable name>', you can run 'gksudo <your qt program executable name>'.